# How to get the list of continuous states blocks in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, solver

I have an **Active power filter** model on **Simulink R2013b** that i want to run on an **Opal-RT OP5600** (Software : **RT-LAB 10.0.7**) simulation platform.

While i try to build the model, i get the following Error :

**the "FixedStepDiscrete" solver cannot be used to simulate block diagram,because it contains continuous states**

I tried to Google the solution, obviously : the Solver can't handle the continuous states blocks, all solutions proposed are : To either change the solver (which is something i can't do because the hardware platform doesn't allow it), so i am stack with the second option which is : **Replace the continuous states blocks with discrete one.**

So my question is :

**how can i get the list of continuous states blocks so i can replace them with discrete one ?**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [State Information](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/state-information.html) in the Simulink documentation. You might be able to do something like that:

```
% Replace vdp by your actual Simulink model
open_system('vdp');
states = Simulink.BlockDiagram.getInitialState('vdp');
```

to get the initial states of the model. States are a snapshot at a particular instant, you can't just get all the model states for all times.

Doesn't the error window points you to the "offending" blocks with continuous states?